# java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind, in spite of no running port

Tags: tomcat, exception, port, camunda, jvm-crash

I am trying to run Camunda BPM tool with embedded Apache tomcat. 
I get to the landing page, but then suddenly the get an `JVM_Bind exception:`

```
27-Mar-2020 13:11:57.277 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
27-Mar-2020 13:06:02.145 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
27-Mar-2020 13:06:02.153 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 45110 ms
27-Mar-2020 13:06:02.155 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]: 
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:382)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:716)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
```

I ran `netstat -ano | find "<port-number>"`

1. 8080 and 8090 ports were not found
2. 8005 was found. 8005 port is the shutdown port configured in `<tomcat>/conf/server.xml`

Update:

```
C:\Users>taskkill /PID 4 /F                                                                                             
ERROR: The process with PID 4 could not be terminated.                                                                  
Reason: Access is denied.
```

Comment: So if you got this when running Tomcat and there was already something listening to port 8005, either it wasn't Tomcat or Tomcat was already running and you should have shut it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there is a system process listening at that port. If that is the case, you need to change your port in `server.xml` file.

Comment: Yes. That was the issue. Some windows program was listening from that port, I had to change my prot configurations.

Answer (score 1):

a) restart the system and check if port is still blocked

b) check running services via "services" menu to identify which program could be running a server

c) stop service or change Camunda server configuration to use other ports e.g. server.xml  `<Connector port="8080"...`